# Python selenium xpath descendant

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Does anyone know how to get a button with:

```
svg[@aria-label='Like']
```

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

I tryed various combinations ... nothing worked.
I worked around with:

```
//button[@class='wpO6b ']
```

But i don't want to use it anymore.
So my trys:

```
//button[@class='wpO6b ']/descendant::svg[@aria-label='Like']
//button[@class='wpO6b' and descendant::svg[@aria-label='Like']]
//button[@class='wpO6b ']//svg[@aria-label='Like']
```

Thanks for reading!

Edit: I want to click the button-element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below `xpath` in your code -

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[local-name()="svg" and @aria-label="Like"]/parent::span/parent::div/parent::button').click()
```

Hope it will detect the button. let me know the outcome.

Comment: Doesn`t worked. But thanks for your thoughts. I should have said that I want to click the element.

Comment: Your code is only wrong for my needs. I want the button. But you gave me the svg-element.

Comment: I have given you the button iteself.. in the `XPath` i have first referred svg-element and then came backward till the button is selected then I have clicked on the same. I have updated my code with the click. Please try that and let me know if this is what you are looking for?

Comment: It clicked, but didn't decide between "Like" and "Unlike"

Comment: Code Updated, Now give it a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218921/discussion-between-pythonologist-and-raphi195).

Comment: @raphi195 looks little messy. try to simplify as `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[.//*[name()="svg" and @aria-label="Like"]]').click()`

Answer (score 0):

Why these one don't work :

```
//button[@class='wpO6b ']/descendant::svg[@aria-label='Like']
//button[@class='wpO6b ']//svg[@aria-label='Like']
```

You select the `svg` element not the button. You have to put the `svg` part inside a predicate.

```
//button[@class='wpO6b' and descendant::svg[@aria-label='Like']]
```

This one is almost good, but since there is a space in the `class` attribute of the `button` element it won't work. It can be fixed  accordingly with a `contains` function which is a more secure option here :

```
//button[contains(@class,'wpO6b') and descendant::svg[@aria-label='Like']]
```

Another way to select the button (using `ancestor` axis and more robust predicates) :

```
//svg[@aria-label="Like" and @fill="#262626"]/ancestor::button[1][contains(@class,"wpO6b")]
```

If you're dealing with `namespaces`, use the following expression :

```
//*[local-name()='button'][contains(@class,'wpO6b') and descendant::*[local-name()='svg'][@aria-label='Like']]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can write xpath:

```
//svg[@aria-label='Like']/ancestor::button[1]
```

Comment: It should work there are different ways an element with the help of different xpath axis. More details in https://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html on how to write xpath

Comment: can you share the url for which your trying to get element.